# WordPress - Set User to Expire after a Certain Date

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a site for a school program. During registration, students are going to be asked to select their graduation year from a dropdown. I want the system to check this value against the current time each time that they log in, and change their roles if the graduation date is past the current time. The code I wrote is below, however I am getting no errors either in logs or WP_DEBUG

```
/* Check if Student Has Graduated and Change Role */
add_action('wp_login', 'check_graduated', 10, 2);
function check_graduated($user_login, $user) {
    /* Ger User Id */
    $user_id = $user -> $id;

    /* Check if Graduation Date exists in DB */
    if($grad_year = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_registration_user_graduation_date', true)) {
        $current_date = time();

        /* Convert Grad Year to Time */
        $grad_date_str = "07/01/" . $grad_year;
        $grad_date = stringtotime($grad_date_str);

        /* Change User Role if Today is Past The Graduation Date */
        if($current_date > $grad_date) {
            change_user_role($user_id, 'former_student', 'student');
        }   
    }
}

function change_user_role($id, $new_role, $old_role) {
    $user = new WP_User( $id );
    $user -> remove_role( $old_role );
    $user -> add_role ( $new_role );
}
```

In the Usermeta table of the database, the following exists:

```
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  UMETA_ID  |  USER_ID  |                 META_KEY                 |  META_VALUE  |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
|     36     |     2     |  user_registration_user_graduation_date  |     2016     |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Like I said, no errors show up when logging in with the user with ID 2. Am I missing something or just dumb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to look at this function  $grad_date = stringtotime($grad_date_str);

It should be

```php
 $grad_date = strtotime($grad_date_str);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Other wise, you should be fairly close.

Comment: I'm dumb. Thanks, checking now

Comment: Thanks, this was part of it. In addition, "$user -> $id" needed to be "$user -> ID", all is resolved now.

Comment: Anytime and thanks for hitting that answer button. 

Another thing you could consider is just using - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/

As close as you were, I didn't want to post a full solution since you had done some trouble shooting and were extremely close.

Comment: The reason i didn't was that I wasn't sure if the wp_login action was called before or after the user session was set, but I will adjust to simplify. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

do you have a method called stringtotime? I think php's time conversion function is strtotime. typo?

Comment: I'm dumb. Thanks, checking now